# Android Spinner from a Directory - Only show part of filepath and only files with a certain extension?

Tags: android, spinner, filepath

I currently have a spinner that is populated using the following;

```
        File sd = new File("sdcard/");
    File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles();
    // String[] filenames = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sdDirList.length; i++) {
        // Log.d("Filename", filenames[i]);
        list.add(sdDirList[i]);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<File> filenameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<File>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    spinSelected.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinSelected.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
    // filename = spinSelected.toString();

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    filename = spinSelected.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

But I have two things I'd like to do with this spinner and can't work out either. The first is to only display files with a .txt extension. As is it displays everything on the sdcard, but I'm only interested in .txt.

In addition, the spinner currently displays the full path of sdcard/filename.extension whereas ideally I'd like it to just show filename - is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to further process your sdDirList array by adding something like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < sdDirList.length; x++)
{
    if(sdDirList[n].getName().endsWith(".txt"))
    {
        // add it to your array adapter
    }
}
```

You may wish to review Java File object doc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. I now have the spinner populating with all the .txt files, in the form sdcard/aa.txt - Is there a way to get it to just display 'aa'?

Comment: Sure.  Check out:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and look at String.replace() and you can just substitute "" (empty string) for any occurrence of ".txt" or you can create a StringBuffer and truncate that.  There are a few ways you can go.  And if you've had your question answered, kindly mark the question as answered rather than just upvoting, so people who run across it in the future will know what worked for you.